# Unwanted "UserControl/" string added automatically to Imagein Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have an `Image` control in the `Repeater` and I assign `ImageUrl` at server side on `ItemDataBound` but I found it strange that it adds "UserControl/" text automatically before the `ImageUrl` I assign. For example:

```
protected void rtTopSinger_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    Image imgSinger = (Image)e.Item.FindControl("imgSinger");
    imgSinger.ImageUrl = "Admin/images/NotAvailable.jpg";
}
```

then it will render like this

```
<img id="ContentPlaceHolder1_TopSingers_rptTopSinger_imgSinger_2"
     src="UserControl/Admin/images/NotAvailable.jpg"
     alt="Image of the Singer diljit dosanjh">
```

Why it is added? How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to use tilde like this,

```
  imgSinger.ImageUrl = "~/Admin/images/NotAvailable.jpg";
```

Assuming that admin folder is at the root of your Website/Application

Because otherwise relative urls will be resolved according to user-control location.

You can start with a slash, but it will not work if your site is setup as virtual directory

```
 imgSinger.ImageUrl = "/Admin/images/NotAvailable.jpg";
```

Comment: I do get these bugs all the time :)